# How to start Kafka with Maven

Tags: maven, apache-kafka

1)How to start Kafka using maven commands ?

2)How to run command prompt commands in maven bat file ?

I want start the kafka server on maven bat file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) Can you explain what *what* you're trying to achieve?  Are you trying to automate a build or test system? If you can give more detail around your question people can help more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is built with Gradle, not Maven, but you should be using the shell scripts provided by Kafka to start it

If you really want to do something like start Kafka then run maven, create your own batch file

```
START /B  kafka-server-start server.properties 
mvn clean install
```

If you are trying to create your own client code using Maven, you can use the Exec Maven plugin to start the main method just as any other application